# Mod_wsgi and Apache. Where is Access-Control-Allow-Origin needed?

Tags: python, apache, apache2, mod-wsgi, access-control

I'm sending data via JS to my apache2 server running mod_wsgi via:

```
$.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "https://annotatie01.io.tudelft.nl/app",
        data: "test-data",
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response)
        }
    });
```

If the .wsgi file i'm sending to is as follows, it works:

```
def application(environ, start_response):
    status = '200 OK'

    length = int(environ.get('CONTENT_LENGTH', '0'))
    data = environ['wsgi.input'].read(length)

    response_headers = [('Content-type', '*'),
                        ('Content-Length', str(len(data)))]
    start_response(status, response_headers)

    return data
```

When I try to save using something like f = open(), or when I try to access a SQL database:

```
import sqlite3

def application(environ, start_response):
    status = '200 OK'

    length = int(environ.get('CONTENT_LENGTH', '0'))
    data = environ['wsgi.input'].read(length)

    conn = sqlite3.connect('/var/database/material3.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute('SELECT image from image_table limit 1')
    data = c.fetchall()   

    response_headers = [('Content-type', '*'),
                        ('Content-Length', str(len(data)))]
    start_response(status, response_headers)

    return data
```

I get an XMLHttpRequest Error > `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.`

I tried added `Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"` to the httpd.conf, as well as to the main Apache configuration, but that did not work. I've always tried adding `('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*')` to the `response_headers`.

How(and where) do I enable access-control-allow-origin, so that I can access the sqlite database, or write something using f = open().

*edit:* My httpd.conf file.

```
 <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
  </IfModule>

<VirtualHost *:443>
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
        ServerName annotatie01.io.tudelft.nl:443
        SSLEngine on

        SSLCertificateFile      /var/www/experiment/CSR/annotatie01_io_tudelft_nl.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile  /var/www/experiment/CSR/annotatie01_io_tudelft_nl.key

        WSGIScriptAlias /app /var/www/experiment/experiment/py/mod_wsgi-test/myapp.wsgi
        DocumentRoot /var/www
        <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/>
            Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
            LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so-2.7
        </Directory>    
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:80>
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
        DocumentRoot /data_nfs/www
        <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory /data_nfs/www>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And my apache2.conf:

```
SSLCipherSuite ALL:!aNULL:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+EXP:+eNULL
SSLProtocol TLSv1
Mutex file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} default
PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}
Timeout 300
KeepAlive On
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
KeepAliveTimeout 5
User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}
HostnameLookups Off
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
LogLevel warn
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.conf
Include ports.conf
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>
AccessFileName .htaccess
<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
        Require all denied
</FilesMatch>
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent
IncludeOptional conf-enabled/*.conf
Include /etc/apache2/httpd.conf
```

Comment: Show your mod_wsgi configuration from the Apache config file so can see where you have specified ``Header`` directive.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton I've added the httpd.conf file.I believe this is the file you're referring too. As you can see, I wasn't sure where to place it.

Comment: Am surprised Apache doesn't give an error when starting, as ``LoadModule`` can't be used anywhere in a ``VirtualHost``.

Comment: As long as I don't attampt to acces outside of the application()  it does work though. Where should the module be loaded instead?

Comment: In your setup you would have a ``wsgi.load`` file in ``mods-available`` directory which contains it. When the module is enabled, that ``wsgi.load`` file would get symlinked into the ``mods-enabled`` directory. That would then be included by the ``IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.conf`` line. Anything to do with global initialisation of mod_wsgi would go in that ``wsgi.conf`` file, such as ``LoadFile`` for Python shared library if necessary, and ``WSGIPythonHome``.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With help from Graham Dumpleton, I managed to get the answer.

I was both loading the module in the httpd.conf, and in the /mods-available/wsgi.load, leading to strange behavior.

Removing the `LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so-2.7` from the httpd.conf caused the module to be loaded correctly. Then the `header` was loaded from the httpd.conf

*edit: added comments info*

Comment: As it has nothing to do with the mod_wsgi module, you wouldn't usually add the ``Header`` directive to ``wsgi.load``. You would keep that in the ``VirtualHost``.